# How to install PyRTF with Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, rtf

I tried to install `PyRTF` from PyPi but this doesn't work.

The package itself can be found:

```
$ pip3 search PyRTF
PyRTF (0.45)  - PyRTF - Rich Text Format Document Generation
```

But installing it fails:

```
$ sudo -H pip3 install PyRTF
Collecting PyRTF
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyRTF (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyRTF
```

I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a Python 3 version of PyRTF called PyRTF3. You can find it [Here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyRTF3/0.47.5).

PS - Use `pip install PyRTF3` or `pip install rtfw` for Python 2, `pip install PyRTF` doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the raw url from the sourceforge page in order to get it:

```
pip install https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyrtf/files/pyrtf/0.45/PyRTF-0.45.tar.gz/download
```

But, to be honest, I don't think this library is maintained on the project website the last update was from `2005`, 11 years ago.. Additionally, it uses a line of the form:

```
from types import StringType
```

which only exists in Python `2.x` not `3.x`. Importing it raises that specific error too:

```
>>> import PyRTF
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jim/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyRTF/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from    PropertySets    import  *
  File "/home/jim/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyRTF/PropertySets.py", line 12, in <module>
    from    types       import  StringType
ImportError: cannot import name 'StringType'
```

So maybe it was designed for `Python 2.x`? I can't remember when `StringType` was removed from the `3.x` series, maybe it targeted an old version of it.

Comment: It seems so @DavidAndreiNed you could contact the author directly to see what's the status for this project. When I gave this answer it wasn't usable in Python `3.5`.